# Retrieve the payment received from an user via Paypal Oauth?

Tags: api, paypal, oauth

I'm trying to retrieve the [list of payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment) received (sales) [on behalf on an user using Oauth](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/get-user-consent/).

I can connect via Oauth successfully, but when I try to retrieve the list of payments with the following request:

```
r = requests.get(
    'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment',
    headers={'authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(access_token)},
    params={
        'count': 100,
        'sort_by': 'create_time',
        'sort_order': 'desc'
    }
)
```

I get an error from the server: **PERMISSION_DENIED**

```
{"name":"PERMISSION_DENIED","message":"No permission for the requested operation","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"33d30d1074b1e"}
```

I'm pretty sure it's related to the scopes I asked when connecting the customer (none for the tests) but when I try to use the following scope:

```
'scope': "openid https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.*"
```

I get the following error : "Scope invalid".

So, how can I retrieve a list of payments on behalf of a user? (just read access!)

Comment: How are you going about doing this in the Sandbox? - I presume you are creating an app e.g. test1 and that's associated with a buyer e.g. seller1@example.com - then you make a  POST /v1/payments/payment request with payee for e.g. seller1@example.com - do you have another id seller2@example.com and you are authorizing seller2 to view seller1's data?

Comment: Not really. I created an application (REST) that I use for OAuth (works well, if I ask for the "openid" scope). I connect to this account with a sandbox one (fake). Again, it works with that scope. But I can't get the list of payments. If I ask for the payments scope, I have the mentionned error.

Comment: so is the flow that you get your merchant to log in with PayPal for a specified scope and then get the token and try to make the call to retrieve the payments on his/her behalf ?

Comment: I'm not sure about your question. I'd say ... yes? I want to retrieve a list of received payments from this merchant.

Answer (score 0):

The error usually occurs if the scope that you are requesting in your API does not have the attributes checked in your app. Check the scope that you are passing in the request and check your app under https://developer.paypal.com ->  Applications -> App Name -> Log In -> Advanced Options -> Expand each of the customize link and check the attributes for the scopes in your request.

Also, if you use different app keys for sandbox vs. production, did you make sure that the appropriate authentication mode is selected?